# Using Terraform module output in other modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform v1.3.8. and have a project that is modularized.

```
    ├── project1/
    │   │   ├── variables.tf
    │   │   ├── main.tf
    │   │   ├── outputs.tf
    ├── project2/
    │   │   ├── variables.tf
    │   │   ├── main.tf
    │   │   ├── outputs.tf
    ├── modules/
    │   ├── ALB/
    │   │   ├── variables.tf
    │   │   ├── main.tf
    │   │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   ├── network/
    │   │   ├── variables.tf
    │   │   ├── main.tf
    │   │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   ├── trgroup/
    │   │   ├── variables.tf
    │   │   ├── main.tf
    │   │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   ├── listener/
    │   │   ├── variables.tf
    │   │   ├── main.tf
    │   │   ├── outputs.tf
```

I am trying to use the outputs values of "trgroup" module in "listener" module.
The main file in project1 is :

```
    # Application load balancer
    module "alb" {
      source                  = "../modules/alb"
      application             = var.application
      public-subnets          = module.network.public-subnet-ids
      ecs_subnets             = module.network.ecs-private-subnet-ids
      pub_alb_security_groups = [module.security.public_alb_security_group]
      int_alb_security_groups = [module.security.internal_alb_security_group]
    }
    
    # Load balancer listener
    module "listener" {
      source                  = "../modules/listener"
      for_each                = var.services
      listener_count          = each.value.listener_count
      application             = var.application
      listener_port           = each.value.listener_port
      ssl_policy              = each.value.ssl_policy
      certificate_arn         = module.cloudfront.certificate_arn
      load_balancer_arn       = module.alb.internal_alb
      listener_protocol       = each.value.listener_protocol
      listener_rule_count     = each.value.listener_rule_count
      type                    = each.value.target_type
      target_group_arn        = module.trgroup.target_group_arn
      srv                     = each.key
    }
    
    #  target groups
    module "trgroup" {
      source                  = "../modules/trgroup"
      for_each                = var.services
      application             = var.application
      trg_port                = each.value.trg_port
      trg_protocol            = "HTTP"
      target_type             = "ip"
      vpc_id                  = module.network.vpc-id
      health_check_path                = each.value.health_check_path
      health_check_port                = each.value.health_check_port
      health_check_interval            = each.value.health_check_interval
      health_check_healthy_threshold   = each.value.health_check_healthy_threshold 
      health_check_unhealthy_threshold = each.value.health_check_unhealthy_threshold 
      health_check_timeout             = each.value.health_check_timeout
      srv                              = each.key
    }
```

the target group main file :

```
    #Target Group
    resource "aws_lb_target_group" "ecs-target-group" {
      name        = "${var.application}-${var.srv}-${terraform.workspace}"
      port        = var.trg_port
      protocol    = var.trg_protocol
      target_type = var.target_type
      vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
      health_check {
        path                = var.health_check_path
        port                = var.health_check_port
        interval            = var.health_check_interval
        healthy_threshold   = var.health_check_healthy_threshold
        unhealthy_threshold = var.health_check_unhealthy_threshold
        timeout             = var.health_check_timeout
      }
    }
    
    output "target_group_name" {
      value = aws_lb_target_group.ecs-target-group.name
    }
    output "target_group_arn" {
      value = aws_lb_target_group.ecs-target-group.arn
    }
    
    the listener main file resource "aws_lb_listener" "alb_listener" {
      count             = var.listener_count
      port              = var.listener_port
      ssl_policy        = var.ssl_policy
      certificate_arn   = var.certificate_arn
      load_balancer_arn = var.load_balancer_arn
      protocol          = var.listener_protocol
      default_action {
        target_group_arn = var.target_group_arn
        type             = var.type
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "listener_rule" {
      count        = var.listener_rule_count
      listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.alb_listener[count.index].arn
      priority     = var.priority
    
      action {
        type             = var.type
        target_group_arn = var.target_group_arn
      }
    
      condition {
        host_header {
          values = var.host_header
        }
      }
```

the target group main file where the output is "target_group_arn" :

```
    #Target Group
    resource "aws_lb_target_group" "ecs-target-group" {
      name        = "${var.application}-${var.srv}-${terraform.workspace}"
      port        = var.trg_port
      protocol    = var.trg_protocol
      target_type = var.target_type
      vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
      health_check {
        path                = var.health_check_path
        port                = var.health_check_port
        interval            = var.health_check_interval
        healthy_threshold   = var.health_check_healthy_threshold
        unhealthy_threshold = var.health_check_unhealthy_threshold
        timeout             = var.health_check_timeout
      }
    }
    
    output "target_group_name" {
      value = aws_lb_target_group.ecs-target-group.name
    }
    output "target_group_arn" {
      value = aws_lb_target_group.ecs-target-group.arn
    }
the listener main file 

    resource "aws_lb_listener" "alb_listener" {
      count             = var.listener_count
      port              = var.listener_port
      ssl_policy        = var.ssl_policy
      certificate_arn   = var.certificate_arn
      load_balancer_arn = var.load_balancer_arn
      protocol          = var.listener_protocol
      default_action {
        target_group_arn = var.target_group_arn
        type             = var.type
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "listener_rule" {
      count        = var.listener_rule_count
      listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.alb_listener[count.index].arn
      priority     = var.priority
    
      action {
        type             = var.type
        target_group_arn = var.target_group_arn
      }
    
      condition {
        host_header {
          values = var.host_header
        }
      }
```

I still get this error:

```
     Error: Unsupported attribute
    │
    │   on main.tf line 24, in module "listener":
    │   24:   target_group_arn         = module.trgroup.target_group_arn
    │     ├────────────────
    │     │ module.trgroup is object with 7 attributes
    │
    │ This object does not have an attribute named "target_group_arn".
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this error by referencing the correct module key since you created the `trgroup` module using `for_each`. So for this to work you would have to do the following:

```
target_group_arn = module.trgroup[each.key].target_group_arn
```

Note that you might encounter the same error might if you are using other outputs where the module which provides the output was created with `for_each`, but the way to fix it remains the same.